# Looking for some mutex-like mechanism for exclusive USB access

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on various USB hardware devices, each of which implementing a serial port.  I'd like to access such serial ports by multiple (Chrome and non-Chrome) applications running on the system in a pseudo-parallel fashion.

Basically I'd like to use some mutex-like atomic primitive so that I could make sure that one application has access to the serial port at the same time and the others are temporarily blocked, waiting for the mutex to be released.

I'm afraid that the Chrome API doesn't offer any such low-level primitives but please disprove me.  Also, I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: You can get at the OS API, surely?

Comment: Not from a Chrome packaged app, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just finished reading the full Chrome packaged apps API and mutexes are definitely not supported but mutexes only work inside a process anyways so it's not what I'm looking for to begin with.

I could create a native app that could bind to multiple ports on the local loopback interface and proxy those connections towards the /dev/ttyACM* serial interface.

The other solution is implementing multiple serial ports for my USB device in the firmware so that multiple clients could connect to my device without interference.

I think I'll go with the latter solution because I don't want to have a daemon proxy running in the background all the time.